# Error iterating a std::vector of pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to copy a std::vector that containing pointers to a class. The function is:

```
Clone::Clone( const Clone &source )
{
    m_pDerivate.clear();

    std::vector<Derivate *>::const_iterator it;
    it = source.m_pDerivate.begin();
    for (it = source.m_pDerivate.begin(); it != source.m_pDerivate.end(); ++it) {
        m_pDerivate.push_back(new Derivate(it));
    }
}
```

And the Derivate constructor is:

```
Derivate::Derivate( const Derivate &source )
{
    _y = source._y; 
    _m = _strdup(source._m);
}
```

But when I compile, I get the following error ...

```
 cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'const Derivate &'
```

... in the line:

```
m_pDerivate.push_back(new Derivate(it));
```

If I change the line by ...

```
m_pDerivate.push_back(new Derivate((const Derivate &)(*it)));
```

... compile fine but the Derivate constructor not receives the data correctly.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to store pointers to `Derived`? You could store `Derived` objects instead, and say `m_pDerivate = source.m_pDerivate`

Comment: Additionally, in a constructor, m_pDerivate, which I assume is a class member, will have just been constructed so won't need clearing.

Answer (score 8):

You need to dereference the iterator and the pointer:

- `*it` is of type `Derivate*`
- `**it` is of type `Derivate`

Change:

```
m_pDerivate.push_back(new Derivate(it));
```

to:

```
m_pDerivate.push_back(new Derivate(**it));
```